# Only display Image in SKShapeNode without overlay color

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm trying to find a way to only display image as texture of SKShapeNode in Swift without any overlay color

Is this possible?

I am using circular shaped nodes and when i try to set `FillTexture` with an image, then i must set also a `FillColor`, that modifies the image. I have tried using `UIColor.clear` but the node completely disappear.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Solved --- You can set `fillColor` to `.white` and the overlay tint color disappear giving image texture its original colors